# Why this groupie does not work to sum up prices?

Tags: pandas

Pandas groupby return multiple value for item_prices as I was trying to sum them up?

```
df.groupby(['order_id']).agg({'item_price':'sum'})
```

This aggregation gave me a list of all the item_prices instead of summing them up:

[df output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shQER.png)

[original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sImEI.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve]. Otherwise there is no way for anyone to suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df.groupby('order_id')['item_price'].sum()
```